# How to remove duplicate elements from arrayList but sum parameter of them?

Tags: java, list, duplicates

There is object Item with parameters name, code, quantity and expiration date. After I've created arrayList from data (.csv) and got sorted list of Items which duplicates.

```
Item name Apples, code 5649.0, quantity 1, exp date 2019-07-03.

Item name Oranges, code 124123.0, quantity 3, exp date 2019-12-04.

Item name Oranges, code 124123.0, quantity 4, exp date 2019-12-04.

Item name Peach, code 946598.0, quantity 1, exp date 2017-11-10.

Item name Tomatoes, code 6.5987989764689741E17, quantity 2, exp date 2019-06-20.
```

Object Item has these attributes

```java
 private String name;

 private double code;

 private int quantity;

 private String expDate;
```

Now I need to remove duplicates but sum the quantity if name, exp date and code is the same (for example to leave one line with Oranges but change quantity to 7 total).

I think about something like that but have no idea what to write inside the loop.

```java
for(Item a : itemsNeed) {
            for(int b=1; b<itemsNeed.size(); b++) {
                if(a.getCode()==itemsNeed.get(b).getCode() && a.getExpDate().equals(itemsNeed.get(b).getExpDate())) {


                }
            }
```

This is what I am thinking about but do not know where to move on. Is it correct? Or is there other easier solution?

Comment: "Is it correct?" do you get the correct result?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo The OP clearly states the input is a CSV file.

Comment: One thing to be careful about: Don't add the same item twice.

Comment: Override `equals` and `hashcode` method of your POJO to use only three fields `name, code and expDate`.  Now, you can use Hashmap in your loop to add your object as key and updated object with summed quantity as value. Before adding , you will check if the key exits, if yes , you update the quantity of value .IF not, you simply add the new object.

Comment: @Jimmy that's terrible idea - `HashCode`/`Equals` is not a place for a business logic! Anyway, implementing what you are suggesting does not require to override any of these methods

Comment: @Dincius I followed your post in the answer, but I find it weird to have `code` as a `double` data type actually.

Comment: @m.antkowicz you are absolutely right that equals/hashcode is no place for business logic. However, OPs use case suggests these objects are same when those three fields are similar hence the need for recalculation of quantity ( of the similar objects).

Comment: Thank you all for advices. Unlucky, I tried them but it doesn't worked for me. Sorry, I am just begginer and mabye made some mistakes. Anyway, I have solved it with for and if loops on my own.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper key composite structure and create a mapper function - then provide it to the `groupingBy` stream collector with `summingInt` downstream, and recreate list of `Item` objects based on collected data

I will use Lombok to present example beneath, but basically what I mean is to create immutable `ItemKey` class with proper `HashCode`/`Equals` implementations and add constructor in `Item` class to recreate `Item` object from `ItemKey` and calculated quantity (this can be implemented another way e.g. using some factory method)

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Item {
    private String name;

    private double code;

    private int quantity;

    private String expDate;

    public Item(ItemKey key, int quantity) {
        this.name = key.getName();
        this.code = key.getCode();
        this.expDate = key.getExpDate();
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}

@Value
class ItemKey {
    private String name;
    private double code;
    private String expDate;
}

// ... 

Function<Item, ItemKey> compositeKey = item -> new ItemKey(item.getName(), item.getCode(), item.getExpDate());

List<Item> filteredAndQuantityAggregated = itemsNeed.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(compositeKey, Collectors.summingInt(Item::getQuantity)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> new Item(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Once again the approach using the `groupingBy` feature of streams, without lombok and some style differences.

The mapping could look like this

```
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<ItemGroupKey, Integer> grouped = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemGroupKey::new, summingInt(Item::getQuantity)));
    List<Item> dedupedSummed = grouped.entrySet().stream()
            .map(t -> t.getKey().getItem().forQuantity(t.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but you need to set up quite a machinery before it can run, where `ItemGroupKey` points out two items as equal, when their name, code and expirationDate are equal. Note, that you have to add the appropriate `hashCode()` implementation too. I chose to use a `Item.forQuantity` method to create a copy of an item with a specific quantity set.

```
   class ItemGroupKey{
    private final Item item;

    ItemGroupKey(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ItemGroupKey other = (ItemGroupKey) o;
        return Double.compare(other.getItem().getCode(), item.getCode()) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(other.getItem().getName(), item.getName()) &&
                Objects.equals(other.getItem().getExpDate(), item.getExpDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(item.getCode(), item.getName(), item.getExpDate());
    }
}

class Item {
    private final String name;
    private final double code;
    private final int quantity;
    private final String expDate;

    Item(String name, double code, int quantity, String expDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.expDate = expDate;
    }

    public Item forQuantity(int quantity){
        return new Item(name, code, quantity, expDate);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public String getExpDate() {
        return expDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Item item = (Item) o;
        return Double.compare(item.code, code) == 0 &&
                quantity == item.quantity &&
                Objects.equals(name, item.name) &&
                Objects.equals(expDate, item.expDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, code, quantity, expDate);
    }
}
```